# Avoiding multiple downloads from AWS S3

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have files on S3 and a program downloads those file every time. Now I want to optimize it by ignoring the already downloaded files. I tried to find many ways like FileUtils.currentDirectory() to save files for the first time and then checking again whether the file is there or not but I was unable to do so.

Pls, suggest.

Comment: I don't need editing suggestions. If you know something, you are most welcomed.

Answer (score 2):

If you wish to have a local copy of files, but only copy new/modified files, you could consider using the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/).

It has an `aws s3 sync` command that only copies new/modified files.

If you wish to do it programmatically, you could copy this behaviour by listing files, then only copying new files or files that have a more recent Modified date.